# Clear the Input value after Click Event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I've got some trouble with Javascript event. I need some code to clear the input value after click. After the input being populated and listed in the "myTable" row, and then the input field go blank.

Here's my code

```
<main>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="gds"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="prc"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="   + Add   " onclick="addField();"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="myTable">
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addField (argument) {
        var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var currentIndex = myTable.rows.length;
        var currentRow = myTable.insertRow(-1);

        var x = document.getElementById("gds").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("prc").value;

        var NumBox = document.createElement("input");
        NumBox.setAttribute("name", "nmbr[]" + currentIndex);
        NumBox.setAttribute("value", 1 + currentIndex);
        NumBox.setAttribute("size", "2");

        var KeyBox = document.createElement("input");
        KeyBox.setAttribute("name", "goods[]");
        KeyBox.setAttribute("value", x);

        var priceBox = document.createElement("input");
        priceBox.setAttribute("name", "price[]");
        priceBox.setAttribute("value", y);

        var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
        currentCell.appendChild(NumBox);

        currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
        currentCell.appendChild(KeyBox);

        currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
        currentCell.appendChild(priceBox);

        currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
        currentCell.appendChild(addRowBox);

        var input1 = document.getElementById("gds");
        input1.reset();

        var input2 = document.getElementById("prc");
        input2.reset();
    }
</script>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code throws an error at this line:

`currentCell.appendChild(addRowBox);`

because the `addRowBox` is undefined (seems to me like its here by mistake). Moreover, you don't use `.reset()` to clear the input value but you simply set its value to an empty string.

So this is probably what you want to have here:

```
    currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
    //currentCell.appendChild(addRowBox);

    var input1 = document.getElementById("gds");
    input1.value = '';

    var input2 = document.getElementById("prc");
    input2.value = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

To clear an input element, simply set its value to an empty string.

```
document.getElementById("gds").value = "";
document.getElementById("prc").value = "";
```

Answer (score -1):

Most basic solution is to use `addEventListener` if you would like to Clear the Input value after Click Event.
Below is the generic code for this purpose.

```
document.querySelector("cssSelector").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
   //yourActionAfterClick
   setTimeout(function(){ 
      //yourDefaultAction 
   }, 3000);
}, false);
```